# Launching zookeeper in a separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, configuration, distributed, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to launch multiple embedded zookeeper servers into separate threads from a Java application this way:

```
String port1 = "2181";
String directory1 = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "zookeeper/data1").getAbsolutePath();
final ServerConfig config1 = new ServerConfig();
config1.parse(new String[] { port1, directory1 });
new Thread(new Runnable() {      
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    try{
      ZooKeeperServerMain zk = new ZooKeeperServerMain()
      zk.runFromConfig(config1);
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }        
  }
}).run();
```

When I start zk this way, the main process is blocked and the remaining instructions are not executed!
Is there a proper way to launch zookeeper in a separate thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `run()` instead of `start()` on your `Thread`.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {      
@Override
public void run()
{
  try{
    ZooKeeperServerMain zk = new ZooKeeperServerMain()
    zk.runFromConfig(config1);
  }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }        
}
}).start();
```